# Visual Studio will stop debugging when selecting "Choose File" in Chrome

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iis-express, visual-studio-debugging

Visual Studio 2017 - 15.8.4 (but happens on previous versions), Windows 7, IIS Express 64. Chrome 64 (Latest when posting).

When I launch Chrome for debugging from within Visual Studio, debugging works fine until I hit "Choose File" to browse a file for upload and selecting a file (not uploading it, just selecting it). Visual Studio debugger will immediately stop without giving any reason.

When using IE's "Browse..." button and selecting a file, which is the equivalent of the same Chrome HTML element, everything is working as expected.

My hunch is that Chrome is trying to do an extra socket connection which is upsetting IIS Express and triggering VS to stop debugging.

Do you know any solution to keep debug running as expected, on Chrome?

Comment: VS2019 + Windows10 19H1 + Microsoft Edge Dev(Chromium), It's still going to stop.

Comment: I had same problem in Yandex but not in Chrome. My problem was solved by turning off extensions. Maybe it might help.

Comment: @MuzafferGALATA you mean extensions from browser?

Comment: Yes sure, browser's extensions..

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled over the same error and for me, it was because I have AVG antivirus installed, and because it starts the debugging in an AVG Secured Chrome instance. I just changed it to normal Chrome, and it stopped exiting debug-mode. Hope it helps!

Comment: In my case, I was using Brave 1.0 as my browser and running into the same issue as the OP. I resolved this issue by switching to Chrome for debugging file inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and I was able to fix it by unchecking 'stop debugging' option in the visual studio settings.

[image: Options]